# rpy2 nls initial parameters choice

Tags: rpy2, nls

Hi I am running a code in python importing rpy2 robjects and trying to make a fit
to some data (with errors that I consider as weights).
I am using a non linear regression and the "formula" i am trying to fit is:
A/((x/t1)^b+(x/t1)^c)

Unfortunately every time I try to run the code I got the usual singular gradient error:

rpy2.rinterface.RRuntimeError: Error in function (formula, data = parent.frame(), start, control = nls.control(),  : 
  singular gradient

I think is due to my initial value for the parameters (A,t1,b and c). 
Is there any way I can have a better guess for the initial values instead just try-outs?
Thanks,
nino

Answer (score 0):

have you checked nlstools in R
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nlstools/

Comment: Yes, but preview is not an rpy2.R object.